# Ruby eventmachine compiling error

Tags: ruby, g++, debian, rvm, eventmachine

I'm getting the following error output when compiling `eventmachine 0.12.10` on `ruby 1.9.2-p290`:

```
g++ -shared -o rubyeventmachine.so binder.o cmain.o cplusplus.o ed.o em.o emwin.o epoll.o files.o kb.o page.o pipe.o rubymain.o sigs.o ssl.o -L. -L/home/git/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib -Wl,-R/home/git/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/git/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib -L/home/git/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib -lruby  -lssl -lcrypto   -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a(functexcept.o): relocation         R_X86_64_32 against `std::bad_typeid::~bad_typeid()' can not be used when making a shared     object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is done on a linux machine running debian squeeze.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try installing EM with the --pre flag. I (probably) had this on another machine and --pre fixed it for me. I'm not 100% sure it was this error, though.

Comment: Alas, no idea then. I'm not really an expert when it comes to Linux. :(

Comment: Thanks anyway. I guess there are some issues with `libstdc++`... I already added the `fPIC`-flag with no luck...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue trying to build mosh-1.2.2 on a standard debian squeeze installation.  The following worked for me:

```
# cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5
# rm libstdc++.so
# ln -s ../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so
```

To explain in a more detail, the existing symlink was pointing to a non-existent file:

```
# cd /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5
# ls -l libstdc++.so
..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      23 May  3  2011 libstdc++.so -> ../../../libstdc++.so.6
..
```

I located the correct file location

```
# dpkg -S 'libstdc'
..
libstdc++6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
..
```

Then repaired the symlink as described in the first code segment.

The error I was getting during compiling was:

```
make[3]: *** [mosh-client] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a(functexcept.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `std::bad_typeid::~bad_typeid()' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/libstdc++.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

No idea how this particular debian squeeze server broke.  I've been compiling on other squeeze systems with no trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your `gcc` installation is bad.

In particular, you have `libstdc++.a` in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/`, but (apparently) not `libstdc++.so`.

The code in `libstdc++.a` was not built with `-fPIC` flag, and so you can't link that code in to a shared library.

Comment: `libstdc++.a` exists in the particular folder and `libstdc++.so`. is symlinked to `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6` which doesn't exist.

How can I recompile this single file without breaking other things? I'm not a C guy at all...

Comment: Btw: `gcc` installation is a debian default one.

Comment: It is very hard to believe that default installation of Debian Squeeze would be missing `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6`. Most likely someone mucked about with your installation, and removed it.

Comment: Hm, upgrading to the latest version of `g++` shipped with wheezy fixed to problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when trying to install `ree 1.8.7-2012.02` with `rvm` or `therubyracer 0.9.9`. The last comment you wrote make me able to correctly fix it, I just use the next command to update g++ to the testing version :

```
sudo apt-get install -t wheezy g++
```

For more informations about keeping a debian system with packages from different releases is in the debian doc [How to keep a mixed system](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-default-version%5d)

Answer (score 0):

upgrading to **ruby 2.2.3** resolved the issue for me

```
$ gcc -v
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
```